# Unexpected slowdown on Advent of Code 2015, day 7

Tags: python

I'm solving the 2015 version of Advent of Code and got, at [day 7](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/7), an unexpected behavior that perhaps someone can help me understand.

The problem asks to compute the values (unsigned 16-bit) that a network of wires produce, like,

```
 123 -> x
 456 -> y
 x AND y -> d
 x OR y -> e
 x LSHIFT 2 -> f
 y RSHIFT 2 -> g
 NOT x -> h
 NOT y -> i
```

I solved this problem with graphs and topological sorting to determine the appropriate order of assignments. However, I also wished to try the much more elegant [solution proposed](https://beautifulracket.com/wires/intro.html) by Matthew Butt­erick that is to interpret the input data as a DSL and let it compute the value itself. The solution at the link is in Racket. I created the following Python version,

```
import re

def uint(i): 
  """ unsigned int """
  return i if i >= 0 else 65536+i

fs = { }   # a dictionary of lambda expressions

with open('input_day7.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    ws = re.split('[ >-]', line.rstrip()) # input pre-processing
    ws = [w for w in ws if w != '']

    if ws[0] == 'NOT':
      fs[ws[2]] = lambda x=ws[1]: uint(~fs[x]())
      
    elif ws[1] == 'AND':
      try:      # int AND y -> z
        fs[ws[3]] = lambda x=int(ws[0]), y=ws[2] : x & fs[y]()
      except:   #   x AND y -> z
        fs[ws[3]] = lambda x=ws[0], y=ws[2] : fs[x]() & fs[y]()
      
    elif ws[1] == 'OR':
      fs[ws[3]] = lambda x=ws[0], y=ws[2] : fs[x]() | fs[y]()
      
    elif ws[1] == 'LSHIFT':
      fs[ws[3]] = lambda x=ws[0], y=int(ws[2]) : fs[x]() << y
      
    elif ws[1] == 'RSHIFT':
      fs[ws[3]] = lambda x=ws[0], y=int(ws[2]) : fs[x]() >> y
      
    else:
      try:     # 123 -> x
        fs[ws[1]] = lambda x=int(ws[0]): x
      except:  #   y -> x
        fs[ws[1]] = lambda x=ws[0]: fs[x]()

print(fs['dw']()) # still works, but 'dy' already takes much more time
```

This program produces the correct results for the example above, but if I try with the [larger input](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/7/input), the program suffers (what seems) an exponential slowdown.

Can anyone explain why is that? Thanks,

Comment: what's the performance (speed-wise) this takes?  Can you share?  I got a old copy and it run quite satisfactory.   (Is lambda function an overhead here, not sure about it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node with the same values could be evaluated many times, as there is no memoization. For example, I see that the "e OR f" is run over a million times.

Comment: I hadn't considered that possibility (nasty network and silly me). And, after a closer look, Butt­erick's post also mentions memoization. Just included a cache into the program and now it's ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses built-in python function eval.
As some wire names match python keywords, I change as, if, in, is, or by my_as, my_if...

```
def subs_operators(line):
  for k,v in {"AND": "&", "OR":"|", "XOR":"^", "NOT": "65536 + ~",
          "LSHIFT": "<<", "RSHIFT":">>"}.items():
    if line.find(k) != -1:
      return line.replace(k,v)
  return line

def subs_keywords(line):
  for k,v in {"as":"zz_as","if":"zz_if", 
              "in":"zz_in","is":"zz_is","or":"zz_or"}.items():
    if line.find(k) != -1 :
      return line.replace(k,v)
  return line
```

with those transformation primitives, input is pre-processed

```
with open("input.txt",'r') as file:
  lines = file.readlines()


lines= list(map(subs_operators, lines))
lines= list(map(subs_keywords, lines))

operations=list(map(lambda x:x.strip().split(' -> '),lines))
```

Now input instructions look like this:

['ba & bc', 'bd']

['jl | jk', 'jm']

['b >> 1', 'v']

['o & q', 'r']

['65536 + ~ p', 'q']

With a list of booleans, I control which operations were evaluated. Initially, all are false

```
ctrl=[] #to control if the operation is evaluable
for op in operations:
  ctrl.append(False)
```

I enter an infinite loop till all operations are evaluated.
In each iteration, I only evaluated operations not evaluated

```
while not all(ctrl):
  for pos, operation in enumerate(operations):
    if not ctrl[pos]: #eval not previously evaluated instructions
      try:
        res = eval(operation[0])
        ctrl[pos]= True
        globals()[operation[1]] = res
      except:
        pass
```

If evals fails, means not all of its inputs have a signal- Exception handler assits me to pass to next operation.

If evals is ok, then toggle control position to true and assign evaluation result to a global variable.

First loop evaluated 7 operations, The second loop evaluated 4 operations ...

it took to me 112 loop inside the while to calculate a = 956

```
print(globals()["a"])
```

my English is not good enough to understand the second part of the exercise.
I changed input line 90 from
14146 -> b
to
956 -> b

but the value i got 40149 is not the correct solution